# Changing properties of Excel for only ThisWorkbook but not other workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say that the default upon opening Excel is that ScreenUpdating = True and Calculation = xlCalculationManual. There are two options that work equally well (as far as I can tell) for changing these properties:

```
thisworkbook.application.screenupdating = false
thisworkbook.application.calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

OR

```
application.screenupdating = false
application.calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

But are these snippets actually doing different things? Does "ThisWorkbook.Application" change these properties only in the workbook from which it's being called? In other words, if I have another workbook open, how do I make sure that my actions in one workbook do not affect the behavior of the other workbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your examples do the exact same thing: they configure the Excel application, not the workbook.

If you need different options for several open workbooks, you need to open them in [SEPARATE instances of Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/force-excel-to-open-new-instance).

And here are [more ways](https://excelgorilla.com/excel/general/open-multiple-instances-excel/) to open instances of Excel.

Comment: That's what I feared. In my case, ThisWorkbook refers to software being deployed to other users, so I can't control how they open other workbooks. Currently, I am using a worksheet to store values of Excel properties upon opening of ThisWorkbook, modifying those properties as needed while running macros in ThisWorkbook, and then returning Excel to the state it was in upon opening. I would like to be able to modify only properties of ThisWorkbook to handle cases where the user opens another workbook in the same instance of Excel, but it appears I can't do this.